# hammer js with carousel images that contain link

Tags: javascript, carousel, hammer.js

I'm using hammer.js with bootstrap carousel for swiping the images left and right with the mouse and it works fine but the problem is the images are links to other pages

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
<a href="#"><img class="imgslide" src="assets/img/07.jpg" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

and when I drag the mouse on it, it swipes but also opens the link, and I want it to only swipe when dragging it and go to the link only when clicking on the image.
I'm using this to make the hammer work:

```
var $slider = $('.carousel'), hammer = new Hammer($slider.get(0));
$slider.find('a').each( (index, elem ) => {
    $(elem).prop('draggable', false);
} );
$slider.carousel();
hammer.on("panleft panright", (e) => {
    
    if( e.type == 'panleft' ) {
        $slider.carousel("next");
    }
    if( e.type == 'panright' ) {
        $slider.carousel("prev");
    }
} );
```

Comment: or please if you can give me a better way to swipe with mouse